# How can I test facebooks friends tagging

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, tags

I want my app to tag friend within a video-post. 
(Posting a video without the tags is working fine)

The account I'm using, has been added to the list of testers for my app. 
So I should be able to do this call without any permissions.

But the response is still:
"error: (#3) Application does not have the capability to make this API call."

To get the "Taggable Friends" permission, I need upload a build of my app to fb.
But I can't implement this feature without testing it by myself first.

How can I solve this chicken-and-egg problem?

My code looks like this (iOS - Objc):

```
NSDictionary *params = @{
                         @"title": @"some title",
                         @"description": @"some desctiption",
                         @"tags": _friendId
                         };
SLRequest *uploadRequest = [SLRequest requestForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook
                                              requestMethod:SLRequestMethodPOST
                                                        URL:videourl
                                                 parameters:params];
```

Comment: You should be able to test anything without review, when using an account that has a role in the app. Are you sure your access token includes the permission necessary to post a video …?

Comment: I'm not using the Facebook SDK, but the Social/Accounts Framework.
This is how I get the token.
ACAccountCredential *fbCredential = [_facebookAccount credential];
    NSString *accessToken = [fbCredential oauthToken];
Is there a way to include permisions?

Comment: I am not familiar with that framework. How it handles login and asking for permissions, you’ll have to look up in its documentation.

Comment: I figured out how to set permissions. Those are the permissions I have tried out:
@"email", @"publish_stream", @"publish_actions",@"read_friendlists",@"user_friends"
But tagging friends is still not working (same error as before).

Comment: I can't find any permission key for tagging friends.
see this list: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/permissions/
And even if I would missing a permission, the error message should be:
"(#200) The user hasn't authorized the application
     to perform this action"
So I gues I have another problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution.
You can't set the tag whithin the upload request (I still don't know why).
But you can tag a user in the video after you uploaded the video.

When the upload succeeded, you get a videoId:

```
NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData
                                                                 options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers
                                                                   error:&error];

            _currentVideoId = json[@"id"];
```

With this id you can make a second request:

```
ACAccountCredential *fbCredential = [_facebookAccount credential];
NSString *accessToken = [fbCredential oauthToken];
NSString *urlStr = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"https://graph-video.facebook.com/%@/tags?access_token=%@&tag_uid=%@", _currentVideoId, accessToken, userId];

SLRequest *request = [SLRequest requestForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook
                                        requestMethod:SLRequestMethodPOST
                                                  URL:[NSURL URLWithString: urlStr]
                                           parameters: @{}];

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^(void) {
    [request performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *responseData, NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error) {

        NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        //Do something
    }];
});
```

To make the second request, you need the permission for @"user_videos".
If you want to tag more users, you need to make this request a few times. Maybe it's also possible with one request, but I didn't figuered out how to do it yet.